# Get rid of the HttpUtility error when compiling google-diff-match-patch in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, google-diff-match-patch

I am getting the following error at compile time when trying to include the C# port of google-diff-match-patch:

> Error 1:  The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context

How do I eliminate this error? I am using the following profile: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.51641, Microsoft Visual C# 2012, Microsoft Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I had to add an explicit reference to the following DLL: **System.Web.dll**.

[image: Add reference to System.Web.dll]